# Apply a CIFilter to a UIView & all subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, core-image, cifilter

I have a `UIView`, that contains a `UIImageView` for its background. The view contains a number of segments (`UIImageView`s), which the user can drag and drop images to. I want to add a `CIFilter` to the whole view, such that any images that are subsequently dropped into the view will have the filter applied instantly. But the filter shouldn't be applied to the main view's background image. I realise that a `CIFilter` requires an input image, I was thinking of using a transparent input image, then placing the filter on top of all the views so it would only be visible when there is an image behind it.

- Is it possible to supply a transparent input image to a CIFilter?
- Is this the best way of going about it?
- I suppose I'd need to mask the filter to the view containing the segments so that it is not applied to the background image. How would I go about this? Since a mask needs an image to mask to, I guess I'd need to render the segments view to an image and mask to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You think wrong way. CIFilter is not like a view that you can place it on top of any view. It is an filter that can process your image and give you processed image. However You should think that when user drag drop any specific imageView in your main view before adding it to to your main view just process its image then add it. Thats all.

Comment: Thanks Ashim. I guess I was just hoping I wouldn't need to do the processing every time an image is added, because there can be quite a few filters to iterate through, which can take a while

Comment: Lot of filter is available in ios6. Check the Core image Framework for further knowledge.